# Intersection of two [or more] decoders

Tags: typescript, decoder

Let's say two decoders are already defined:

```
import * as D from "decoders"
const named = D.object({
  firstName: D.string,
  lastName: D.string
})

const aged = D.object({
  age: D.number
})
```

How do I get an *intersection* of these existing decoders, such it validates for an `object` containing properties from both?

```
const person: D.Decoder<{
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string,
  age: number
}> = D.???(named, aged)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like the library has a function for that.
Here is how it could be done

```
import { Ok } from "lemons/Result";
function combine<A, B>(decoder1: D.Decoder<A>, decoder2: D.Decoder<B>): D.Decoder<A & B> {
  return (blob: unknown) =>
    decoder1(blob).andThen((v1) => decoder2(blob).andThen((v2) => Ok({ ...v1, ...v2 })));
}

const person = combine(aged, named);
```

Or if the decoders are `inexact` instead of `object`:
(This will fail if they are not `inexact` and the type checker won't catch it)

```
function combine<A, B>(d1: D.Decoder<A>, d2: D.Decoder<B>) {
  return D.compose(d1, d2) as unknown as D.Decoder<A & B>;
}
```